# Using a variable outside the main method

Tags: methods

Okay, so I have this simple, but huge problem, to which I really cannot find the solution. I have declared all the variables outside the main method and then gave them values in the main method, but i can't seem to link them, so when i call them in other classes the Strings author1 and 2 are empty and so is my array Artists. I will appreciate very much any help of yours, it is driving me crazy and i am in hurry.

```
package Medienbibliothek;
```

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Artist extends Author{

```
 static String FirstName1;
 static String NickName1;
 static String LastName1;
 static String artist1;

 static String FirstName2;
 static String NickName2;
 static String LastName2;
 static String artist2;


public static String[] artists = new String[]{artist1, artist2};

public static void main(String args[]){



Scanner Person = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter FirstName: ");
FirstName1 = Person.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter LastName: ");
LastName1 = Person.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter NickName: ");
NickName1 = Person.nextLine();

String artist1 = (FirstName1 + " " + "\"" + NickName1 + "\"" + " " + LastName1);

System.out.println("Your first artist is: " + artist1);

System.out.println("Enter FirstName: ");
FirstName2 = Person.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter LastName: ");
LastName2 = Person.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter NickName: ");
NickName2 = Person.nextLine();

String artist2 = (FirstName2 + " " + "\"" + NickName2 + "\"" + " " + LastName2);

System.out.println("Your second artist is: " + artist2);



System.out.println("Your artists are: " + "\n1." + artist1 + "\n2." + artist2);

final String[] artists = new String[]{artist1, artist2};

System.out.println(Arrays.asList(artists));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `String artist1` inside a function it declares new local variable, which 'shadows' `static String artist1;`. It means that inside the following code `artist1` will refer to local variable and not the static one. Remove these unnecessary declarations.

Comment: Yeah, i did that, it worked, but another problem occured. You see that i have assigned values to artist1 and artist2 and I want them to be saved in my array artists, so i can use it in other classes. When i try to do it, it says that the array is consists of two null variables.

Comment: I want to enter them once, save them as final and then use them permantently.

Comment: @PeterGeorgiev - did you keep the assignment `artist1 = (FirstName1 + " " + "\"" + NickName1 + "\"" + " " + LastName1);`? There is no way to have them `static final`. This would mean that they have to be initialized during static initialization - before `main` even begins.

Comment: I kept it and i have actually no idea how i to change the code to achieve what i want haha. I removed all the finals and kept the static assignments before the main. I just want to declare the values only once with the scanner, then store and use them.

Comment: @PeterGeorgiev - you can't have assignments before you have data to assign ready.